# Constraining an xs:any element with some predefined attributes

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I am trying to create an XSD schema where I have a root element, namely context, with some attributes and any sub-elements.

But the problem is: these sub-elements are subject to have some attributes as well. In other way to express, there can be any number of child elements in context elements, but these child elements must have some required and optional attributes.

When I try to create the schema with *Liquid Studio*, it doesn't allow me to write any content in `xs:any` element to define attributes. And I could not find a solution on the internet.

Is there any way to define some constraints to an `xs:any` element?

Below is a SS from my attempted code : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's an unfortunate limitation of `xs:any` wildcards that you can't constrain the type/content of the elements that match, you can only constrain their element names.

In XSD 1.1 you can get around this by using assertions.